# Soft question: What does it mean if the area integral of the divergence of a vector field over a region is negative?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, soft-question

Let $\vec{F}(x,y)$ be a vector field over $\mathbb{R}^2$ and let $\nabla \cdot \vec{F}$ be its divergence.  Presume that $\delta$ is a circle in the $x,y$ plane.  If I compute:

$$I = \int\int_\delta \nabla \cdot \vec{F}dA$$

and find that $I < 0$, what does that mean?  Is it correct to say that the net flux of the vector field acrosss the boundary of that region is negative?  Is it further correct to say that $\vec{F}$ has more sinks than sources in that region?

Comment: if $I<0$ wouldn't that mean there are more sinks in $\delta$ than sources?

Comment: Yes, good catch.  I've edited it

Comment: ok so the answer to your two questions are "yes" and "yes". Is there a particular reason you raised these questions?

Comment: Yes :-)  I have a specific application in mind.  My vector field is a field of velocities.  I want to know, if I place a particle inside of this region and have its velocity equal to the value of the vector field, if its trajectory will always keep it within the region (that is, whether it can even "flux out" of it) given the conditions above

Comment: well then that's the question you should have asked (and you should probably edit your qn with the appropriate tags, particularly ODEs):)

Comment: I suppose I can ask a second question to that affect.  This one was still a question I had, so if you'd like to take your comments and put them into an answer I'll accept it, and then post the more precise question

Comment: @TedShifrin thanks, edited

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answers to your two questions in the post are "yes" and "yes". As for your question in the comments about the velocity field, the answer is no. As a concrete example, consider $F:\Bbb{R}^2\to\Bbb{R}^2$ defined as $F(x,y)=(x,-2y)$. Then, $\nabla \cdot F = -1$, so it has constant negative divergence (by slight modification, this works in any number of dimensions).

On the other hand, the integral curves with initial condition at $p=(a,b)\in\Bbb{R}^2$ are given by
\begin{align}
\gamma_p(t)&= (ae^t, be^{-2t})
\end{align}
In other words, if you start your particle at position $p=(a,b)$, and you let it "flow along the vector field" then the above curves are what you get (you can easily see they satisfy $\gamma_p'(t)=F(\gamma_p(t))$ together with the initial condition $\gamma_p(0)=p$).

Look closely at the solution, it has the $e^t$ term which explodes. So, as a very concrete illustration, suppose $p=(1,0)$, so your particle is originally 1 unit away on x axis. Them, $\gamma_{(1,0)}(t)=(e^t,0)$, so as time goes on the particle goes off to infinity, even though the vector field has constant negative divergence.

This apparent mismatch comes from the fact that the integral $\int_D\text{div}(F)\,dA = \int_{\partial D}F\cdot n\, dl$ measures the flux across the entire boundary, which is like a "net effect". On the other hand, we can focus our attention to specific directions (like the $x$-axis in my example), where everything could be exploding, and totally disregard the other directions.