# Particle trajectories in a vector field with certain conditions

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, multivariable-calculus

Presume I have a vector field over $\mathbb{R}^2$, $\vec{F}(x,y)$, that describes particle velocities.  I furthermore know the following about this field:

Within some region, $\delta$ (which is actually just a region bounded by the unit circle in my particular problem, but I'm interested in a more general answer over a region bounded by some closed simple curve), I know that:

$$\int\int_\delta \nabla \cdot \vec{F} dA < 0$$

From a previous question I asked, I understand this means that the net flux of the velocity field within this region is negative and thus the velocity field has more sinks than sources there.  The question I now have is: is the above information sufficient to claim that a particle that begins within this region will always stay within this region?  If not, what other conditions would I need in order to guarantee this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I contemplated for a while whether I should answer here or your previous question, but ultimately I decided not to clutter up my [previous answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4146842/568204). If you recall, the issue we had there is that the vector field had different behavior along different direction. In order to get a result of the type you're after, we need to suitably restrict the behavior of the vector field along every direction; the divergence alone does not give a sufficient restriction.

If you have access to it, I'd suggest taking a look at Hirsch and Smale's textook on ODEs, particularly, the section on non-linear sinks. First here are some definitions:

> Let $U\subset \Bbb{R}^n$ be open, $F:U\to\Bbb{R}^n$ a $C^r$ mapping (we call this a $C^r$ vector field). A point $a\in U$ such that $F(a)=0$ is called an equilibrium point.
>
> An equilibrium point $a$ such that every eigenvalue of $DF_a$ has negative real part is called a sink of the vector field $F$.

Now, one can prove the following theorem (proof is in the book):

> Let $F:U\to\Bbb{R}^n$ be a $C^1$ vector field, and $a\in U$ a sink of $F$. Then, there exists an open neighborhood $A$ of $a$ in $U$ such that:
>
> - for any point $p\in A$, the initial value problem $\gamma_p'(t)=F(\gamma_p(t))$, $\gamma_p(0)=p$ has a solution defined for all $t>0$, and furthermore, $\gamma_p(t)\in A$ for all $p\in A, t>0$.
>
> In fact, all nearby solutions converge to $a$ exponentially. More precisely, let $\mu$ be the minimum of the absolute values of the real-parts of the eigenvalues of $DF_a$. Then, with $A$ as above, there exists a constant $C>0$ such that for all $p\in A$ and all $t>0$, we have
> \begin{align}
> \lVert \gamma_p(t)-a\rVert \leq Ce^{-\mu t}\lVert p-a\rVert.
> \end{align}

In other words, if you have a sink, then all nearby integral curves will in fact converge to the sink at an exponential rate. I'm guessing this is the kind of picture you have in mind with a vector field like $F(x)=-x$ (i.e all the arrows "pointing inward towards the origin")
.

Comment: Thanks and yes, you're right that the answer here is more suitable than on the other question.  This answers it handily